# What is the correct way to run a php script in Spring DSL camelconfig.xml file in an apache camel project?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Spring DSL, apache camel 2.10 and trying to create a route that calls a php script.

```
<route id="HTTPtoJMS">
<from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8888/placeorder" />
<inOnly uri="jms:incomingOrders" />     
<to uri="language:php:/home/rosh/test/getAllBills.php" />
</route>
```

I start it as a war in apache tomcat 7, and the webapp starts without exceptions.
However, at runtime, I get :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No script engine could be created for: php

What am I doing wrong?

I browsed the very few resources on how to call php from spring dsl, such as  http://camel.apache.org/book-languages-appendix.html , but couldn't find what i am doing wrong.

I have in my pom.xml the dependency for scripting languages.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-script</artifactId>
  <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just an update:

Got it working for now by this method, using exec component instead of script.

<to uri="exec:/usr/bin/php?args=/home/rosh/test/getAllBills.php"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camel-script component uses the Java Scripting API. And you would need to install a PHP Scripting Engine in your JVM to support this. There is a few that comes out of the box with the JVM, I think one such is JavaScript.